# Flutter PWA not showing `Add to Home Screen` option

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Flutter version: `1.19.0-4.0.pre`

I am trying to generate a PWA app using Flutter web, but when I open the web app, it doesn't behave as a PWA should and it doesn't show `add to home screen` banner either on my android device.

Here's my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "Flutter PWA Demo",
  "short_name": "PWA Demo",
  "start_url": ".",
  "scope": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
  "theme_color": "#E50D7F",
  "description": "A Flutter pwa application.",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried it on `master` and `dev` but it doesn't work. It doesn't show `add to home screen` option on device or desktop chrome browser.

Comment: Are you generating the manifest.json or is `flutter build web` doing it for you?

Comment: @JoseGeorges I have added `manifest.json` myself.

Comment: I did the same, which I find odd I think this should be generated with `flutter build web`. Also, I fixed the issue (in my case) by noticing there was a file the service worker was requesting that wasn't on my environment (inside the assets folder), I added a blank file with the name and it worked. Kind of specific so I'm not creating an answer unless this fixes your problem as well.

Comment: could you tell me the name of that file?

Answer (score 1):

Firt become sure that you have registered "flutter_service_worker.js" in your "index.html" file, just like below:

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("/flutter_service_worker.js");
  });
}
```

Then open your pwa on chrome, right click on page and select "Inspect" option. Then go to "Application" tab and check if there is an error for "Manifest" and if there is you should fix it.
Then check "Service Workers" tab to see if "flutter_service_worker.js" is registered.
If it is registered and the "Manifest.json" file works fine, then you should see "Add to Home screen" option.

Comment: @BirjuVachhani Is there any error in the "Manifest" tab or "Service Workers" tab?

Comment: I just check today and surprisingly it seems to be in current flutter master branch. I traced the issue back to caching functionality. The method was returning different value. Now it seems to be working fine.